# Historial de cursos en una base de datos Access

Tags: base-de-datos, ms-access

Mi problema es que estoy haciendo una base de datos en Access, es muy sencilla, tan solo tiene las tablas de Alumnos y Cursos, vinculadas entre sí, para que los cursos agrupen a los alumnos. Mi problema viene cuando un alumno cambia de curso, ¿cómo podría guardar en un historial los cursos anteriores a los que ha pertenecido un alumno? Para que al añadirlo al curso nuevo se mantenga en algún sitio en el curso que estuvo anteriormente.

Gracias

Comment: Necesitas 3 tablas obligatoriamente. La primera, la de alumnos, la segunda, la de información de los cursos. Y una tercera, que, por ejemplo, se llame MATRICULACIONES, con dos campos de fecha de alta y fecha de baja. En esta tercera tabla, ve dando de alta y baja a los alumnos en diferentes cursos. Te permitirá hacer lo que quieres.

Comment: Ok, muchísimas gracias @ElierSánchezE-Infantes. Además de esos dos campos debería añadir el campo para vincular al alumno y el campo para vincular el curso, no?

Comment: Sí, claro. Esta tabla MATRICULACIONES, mínimo, debería tener 5 campos. ID Matrícula (sería el nº de matrícula, y sería tu clave principal), otro campo alumno donde vincules con la tabla donde estén los datos de tus alumnos, otro campo curso donde vincules con la tabla donde estén los cursos, y las fechas de alta y baja, para saber cuándo se apuntaron a un curso, y cuando lo dejaron.

Comment: Perfecto, muchísimas gracias de nuevo @ElierSánchezE-Infantes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes crear una tabla Historial, que tenga una referencia al alumno y otra al Curso. Algo así:

"Create table historial (Date inicio, Date final, int alumnoId references Alumnos(alumnoId), int cursoId references(cursoId)).

Es una idea. Ahora que vas a requerir manejo de transacciones al actualizar cursos de alumnos.

Comment: Transacciones? a qué te refieres?? Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: El manejo de transacciones es para cuando vas a actualizar varios registros y quieres que se procesen todos o ninguno, ya que sino pudiera haber inconsistencias. Por ejemplo, si vas a dar de baja un alumno de un curso, vas a hacer cambios en la tabla Cursos y en la tabla Historial. Tu base de datos no va a estar consistente si se actualiza una tabla y luego no se actualiza la otra. Tipo por fallas de luz u otras causas. Para eso se requieren las transacciones.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias por la aclaración.